# How to write <script> in $scope style

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I'm implementing google map into my ionic app, and I have a script in my index.html, which, will only allow the map works in the index.html.

But I need my map in my templates file route.html instead, so I believe I should move the script in the index.html to the specific controller.js file, but things here are written in $scope style, can anyone tell me how could I wrote the  style into $scope style?

And why actually things won't works in the route.html as the same code is used?

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Here's my script in my index.html:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

And my controller in the controller.js

```
.controller('RouteCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
$scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
$scope.map = map;
};

$scope.centerOnMe = function () {
console.log("Centering");
if (!$scope.map) {
  return;
}

$scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
  content: 'Getting current location...',
  showBackdrop: false
});

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
  console.log('Got pos', pos);
  $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
  $scope.loading.hide();
}, function (error) {
  alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
});
}





})
```

Answer (score 0):

There 2 ways to solve your problem :

1. Change your script to angular method in controller or create a service , like:

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: $scope.map,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         position: latLng
     });

   var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: "Here I am!"
     });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
         infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
     });
2. Change it to jquery in controller, but it not recommend because it will break to purpose of angular usage in ionic:

   var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map"), {
         zoom: 4,
         center: uluru
       });

Comment: Or is there any way to write the script in the ion content or view?